# Are there really 200 000 maids in one building?

Tags: translation

Text:

> 同じ頃のとある日曜日、20万の「メイド」と呼ばれる外国人家事労働者が働く香港のあるビルの一部屋では、演劇ワークショップを行うフィリピン人家事労働者たちの姿があった.

My translation:

> Around the same time on a Sunday, 200000 'maids' - what foreign domestic house labourers are called - work in one room in a Hong Kong building. Filopino domestic house labourers who perform a stage workshop can be seen.

There's something wrong with my translation but I can't pick it up. Are there really 200 000 maids in one building or one in each building? Can someone help me tell me why I'm wrong? And what a good translation would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly a confusing sentence, but I think 20万の…家事労働者が働く only modifies 香港, not 香港のあるビル.

> In a room of a building in Hong Kong, where 200,000 foreign house labourers (known as "maids") work, there were ...